# Are there any country- or city-specific dishes I can try whilst in Dakar, Senegal?

Tags: food-and-drink, senegal, dakar

I'd like to know what traditional foods/dishes exist, if any, and how I should go about locating places that sell them :) I am not really looking for modern cuisine, I'm looking for local food that someone's mother might make.

Comment: If you go to Dakar and like burgers, don't forget to go to the burgers in the city center. There I could taste the best burguers in my life.

Answer (score 5):

The number one in Senegal is the so called [Yassa Poulet](http://www.congocookbook.com/chicken_recipes/poulet_yassa.html). It is made of chicken and rice with a delicious sauce. There are a lot of interesting dishes more, but Yassa Poulet is specially easy to find in any place and delicious.

[image]

Comment: Yassa is nice, but I would recommend thiebu jen, specially homemade.

Answer (score 2):

As a senegalese, I recommend you:

1. Thiebu jen
   This the most popular dish in Senegal. It looks like Spanish paella, but thiebu is more tasty. Home made is better than what they serve in the restaurant.
   [image]
2. Yassa
   Made off onions marinating with mustard, lemons. Usually server with Chicken. Fish yassa also is yummy.
3. Maffe
   West africa style curry.
   There are different kinds:

   - Maffe with peanut butter
   - Maffe with okrah
   - Sour maffe

Comment: These sound fantastic! Just out of curiosity, do any of these have vegetarian options?